# PayPal transactions in Russian Ruble

Tags: paypal, currency

I'm using embedded payments on my website, payment transactions are initiated directly from buyers to sellers and the service acts as an API caller. The price for goods is set in USD by sellers to simplify international trading.

When the sender and receiver are Russian residents the sender gets an error:

```
The payment you initiated has been blocked because PayPal can only facilitate payments between Russian residents when they transact in Russian Ruble. 
Please go back to the merchant website and choose to pay in Russian Ruble, or alternatively choose another payment method.
```

PayPal docs do not list Russian Ruble as possible currency in any of Adaptive Payments API calls, so when I try to specify 'RUR' currency I get `"Currently the system does not accept the currency RUR"` error.

So the question is how can I create transaction between Russia residents if required currency is Russian Ruble and it's not supported by API?

Comment: I've found that currency should be RUB, not RUR, but now I get just "Internal Error" from PayPal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this question before and was not able to find a definitive answer. As far as I was able to determine, it is simply impossible for Russian PayPal accounts to pay each other using Adaptive Payments -- but it may be possible if they manually (without Adaptive Payments) 'Send Money' within one account to another in Rubles.  I know this isn't the most helpful answer but it's the best information I have.

Comment: Seems to be true, at least for now. I knew that PayPal is limited in Russia, but this point makes it really useless for local e-commerce.